# how to scan bar-code without datawedge in motorola device with android OS

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, motorola, datawedge

I'm currently doing an application in Motorola MC40 device to scan the barcode. In order to do that i need to register the activity in datawedge app. Can i do a scan without creating the profile or registering the activity in datawedge?

Note: I have done a sample app which registers the activity in datawedge with the help of this [link](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/community/android/android-forums/android-blogs/blog/2014/11/06/scanning-barcodes-in-your-xamarin-android-app)

Answer (score 2):

You can scan without creating a datawedge profile because by default a generic scanning profile is present but that just provides the scanned data as keyboard input.

You should take a look at the [Symbol EMDK for Android](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/community/android/emdk). This would allow you to control the scanner either through an API or create a datawedge profile directly within your application (The later being simpler). With a profile You'll have the ability to set barcodes decoders, data output, enable the scanning on certain activities, and set a custom Intent action.

Comment: Just to add on the already existing answer: when scanning directly using Symbol.XamarinEMDK, the application will get exclusive access to the barcode scanner, effectively blocking other apps that may want to access the scanner.

This is basically why DataWedge exists: to allow multiple apps to concurrently share the barcode scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the link you provided in your question is for using Xamarin, I can assume that you're using Xamarin and C# to build your Android application for the Motorola Solution (now Zebra Technologies) MC40.

Few notes:

1. The device comes out of the box with a default profile (Profile0) that is enabled by default in every activity, you can modify that so that it send the data as an intent instead of using the keyboard entry mode.  From there you can follow the tutorial you linked.
2. You can integrate the Symbol EMDK in your Xamarin application an programmatically create the DataWedge Profiles you need in your app. To do this using Xamarin, you need to create a binding for the com.symbol.emdk.jar library used by the EMDK. There's a [tutorial](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2813) that is available and Zebra Technologies will release new tools to make this simpler in the future.
3. If you're manually create a DataWedge profile on one device and you need to deploy this on multiple devices, you can export it and put in on the folder `/enterprise/device/settings/datawedge/autoimport`. The profile will be imported automatically by DataWedge. This (and more) is explained in the [MC40 Integrator Guide](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=92721&productDetailGUID=d476e3883f840410VgnVCM10000081c7b10aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=2202caf8fb16e310VgnVCM1000000389bd0aRCRD).